# Last grid_forget does not update parent

Tags: tkinter

The LabelFrame f is updated after the first grid_forget, but not after the second. Why?

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
f = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='The frame')
l1 = tk.Label(f, text='Label1')
l1.grid()
l2 = tk.Label(f, text='Label2')
l2.grid()

f.after(3000, l1.grid_forget)
f.after(6000, l2.grid_forget)
f.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the last child of the frame is removed, `grid` no longer "owns" the window, so it doesn't know that it needs to resize the frame.

The simplest solution is to place a tiny 1x1 pixel frame in there which will keep `grid` as the manager of the widgets within the frame.

Comment: Ah, great! The only thing I actually want to do, in my real code, is to always trigger the configure event in the parent of f (also when removing the last child widget). I understand that this patch will do that, but maybe I can do that directly? But I can definitely go with your solution also. Isn't this "remove from grid at removal of last child"-behaviour a bug, or is it really a feature that is used? I really appreciate your answers. All of them...

Comment: @FredrikJohansson: I don't know if it's classified as a bug or not.